# How can i read from a vector of strings in c++

Tags: c++

for example how can i read just the first character of the first string:

```
vector <string> vec= {"aa","ab","abc","efg"};
```

Thank you.

Comment: like `vec[0][0]`

Comment: `vec.front().front()` should also do it. But I'm not sure what you're really asking.

Comment: I see that you need a c++ book not just an answer. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: If you know how to reference a single element of your vector, you have a string. If you know how to reference a single element of a string, you have a character. Chain the two together, and baby? You got a stew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read it like this:

```
std::vector <std::string> vec = { "aa","ab","abc","efg" };
std::vector<char> result;
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
{
    result.push_back((*it)[0]); // (*it)[0] == vec[i][0]
}
```

Now result is a vector of first elements of each string

Comment: That would be an iterator loop. An index loop, range-for loop, or [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) algorithm could all accomplish this as well. Hard to say what the OP is really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yeap, I know. Provided example of code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

A vector just stores stuff you put in it, in this case, std::strings. To access the first element of a vector, as you said, there are [multiple ways](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of doing that. The easiest, if you are used to arrays, is just using []:

```
std::string myString = myVector[0]; // store the first string of myVector
```

The second question is, how to access a character of a string, again, there are [multiple ways of doing that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), but again you can use []:

```
char myChar = myString[0]; //store the first character of myString
```

Also tip: [It is generally frowned upon to use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)